# My table cell is overflow-y, when I tried to export to PDF format using html2canvas it only capture the half of table cell

Tags: jspdf, html2canvas

Below is my code for exporting the data cell to pdf format...

```
html2canvas(document.getElementById('value_export'), {
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                var data = canvas.toDataURL();
                var docDefinition = {
                    content: [{
                        image: data,
                        width: 1300
                    }],
                    pageSize: 'A3',
                    pageOrientation: 'landscape'
                };
                pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download("timesheetSubissionReport.pdf");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Is that any way to export to pdf format and capture all the data cell, even though the data is overflow in y axis , please help ! thank you

Comment: Hi @nobody ! Please reformat a little bit your post - what you are trying to achieve, the issue and what did you tried already